# Running Sphinx 2.2.11 with MySQL 5.7 is not working

Tags: mysql, sphinx, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I am willing to run `Sphinx 2.2.11` with `MySQL 5.7`
I have installed MySQL 5.7 and it is working fine using `Homebrew`. I also installed `Sphinx 2.2.11` using `Homebrew`, which installed `MySQL 8` dependency. 
I unlinked `MySQL 8` and forced linked `MySQL 5.7`
Now every time I run sphinx with `indexer --all` I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/mysql55/mysql/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/sphinx-2.2.10-release-osx10.10-x86_64/bin/indexer
  Reason: image not found
[1]    5548 abort      indexer --all
```

If I used MySQL 8, I won't get this error.
I don't know whether the problem is related to the config file I am running sphinx or what exactly.

I also do not have an `/opt/` directory.

I will be glad to get help on that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```